# How to disable format option in windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2012, format

I want to disable the 'format' option in right click menu for all the drive.

It is just a precautious action to avoid accidental formation of drives.

Comment: I am sure, This is a valid qns. Why down voted ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking... first you talk about removing a format option for all drives, you then mention about creating a new user? Are you talking about people using the server, or preventing users from formatting drives from client (domain joined) computers - i.e. Group Policy?

Answer (score 0):

If this is just something you are doing for yourself, you could potentially rename the file at C:\Windows\System32\format.com to something like format.com.old.

If this is to manage a group of users, I would instead suggest giving them non-administrative rights to the server.  I'd even suggest doing this for your own account, so that you are forced to enter a true admin password each and every time you wish to change something important on the server.

Comment: I have seen in many websites the suggested method is,  renaming the format.com. Is it correct way ? will it not harm in any other way ? 
Even If I totally miss the format functionality in Windows I am happy with that, But will not affect in any other way ?

Comment: I don't know if I'd say it's the "correct way".  It just means you wont be able to format anything (hard drives, USB drives, etc). I'd personally prefer making user accounts without administrative rights, but this hack should still work for you.